# how to get value of previous row in sas

Tags: sas

How to get value of previous row , for eg, in first row value of `C` column is 95 , it should get added to 2nd row of `A` column , then i want to substract `A-B` column value will be 89, then 89 should added to 3rd row `A` column and so on till `LAN` column value is same , for new LAN `A-B = C, C` value gets added in next row column `A`,

i used LAG function while capturing the value of previous column, but got stuck when new `LAN` available

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not following all the logic, but the by-group lagging can be handled like this.

```
data have;
input Lan A B C;
datalines;
123 100 5 95  
123 95  6 89  
123 89  7 82  
123 82  8 74  
456 500 2 498 
456 498 3 495 
456 495 4 491 
456 491 5 486 
789 600 6 594 
789 594 7 587 
789 587 8 579 
;

data want;
   set have;
   by Lan;
   lagC = ifn(first.Lan, ., lag(C));
run;
```

Comment: How IFN works ?

Comment: If the first.Lan = 1 then lagC = .   . If not, lagC = lag(C)

Comment: Its not working Peter

Comment: It sure is. As statet, I don't follow your logic. The code above creates simple lags, considering by-groups. If you want a fully workable code example, post your exact desired result.

Comment: sure peter i will share thorough question

Comment: Please add to your question the following information: What are your input values and what are the resulting values? Do you have a certain starting value for each LAN? (e.g. 100 for 123 and 500 for 456)? How do you get the values for the subtraction ? (e.g. 5, 6, ,7 and 8 for LAN 123) ? Is it a starting value like 5 and then you add 1 per line ?